# Using a join statement on a table returned from a function

Tags: postgresql

The following function returns a table of user_id, username and password:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_usernames() RETURNS TABLE
        (   user_id integer,
            username text,
            password text
        ) AS $$

        SELECT user_id, username, password FROM users 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

How do I use this table to join on another table THAT IS NOT A FUNCTION using the user_id value returned by the function.
for example if i wanted to use this function to do a join like so:

```
INNER JOIN tablex ON get_usernames().user_id  = tablex.user_id
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: `from tablex join get_usernames() un on un.user_id = tablex.user_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yours replied! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT holiday.user_id, username, start_date 
FROM holiday 
   inner join get_usernames() AS tablex ON holiday.user_id = tablex.user_id;
```

That is what fixed it.